# PgAdmin not working with Postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, postgresql-9.5

I am connecting to a postgresql docker service with the following commands :

```
docker create --name postgres-demo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Welcome -p 5432:5432 postgres:11.5-alpine
docker start postgres-demo
docker exec -it postgres-demo psql -U postgres
```

I can successfully connect to postgresql conatiner service
[image]

Now I want to connect to PgAdmin4 to make some queries to the existing data in postgres database
However I keep having this error
[image]

The IP address that I am using is the one I extracted from docker inspect DOCKERID

[image]

I have restarted the postgresql service on windows but nothing happens. What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, what you get with `docker inspect`(172.17.0.2) is just the ip of container, to visit the service in container, you need port binding host's port to container's port.

I see you already used `-p 5432:5432` to do it, so please get the ip of host using `ip a s`, then if you get e.g. `10.10.0.186`, then use this host ip to visit the service, use `5432` as a port.

> To publish a port for our container, we’ll use the --publish flag (-p for short) on the docker run command. The format of the --publish command is [host port]:[container port]. So if we wanted to expose port 8000 inside the container to port 3000 outside the container, we would pass 3000:8000 to the --publish flag.

A diagram let you know the topologic of docker network, FYI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try to connect to:

```
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 5432
```

while your docker container is up and running.

Comment: I needed to close my postgresql service and only have my docker up and running